# Xampp Mysql attempting to Start

Tags: mysql, xampp

[image]

Guys help me, I already changed the port to 3307 and already uninstalled my other Mysql but xampp mysql still not starting.

Comment: do you have any other mySQL installed in machine ?

Comment: I already uninstall them

Comment: You need to have MySQL in your system in order to configure it!!
The best thing is to uninstall the previous xampp bundle and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

GO to the configuration file (it can be different in your case):
**"C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini"**

Change the port number to some other number and restart the system.

Hope it works

Comment: I didnt find any port number here